# OpenLayers - Vector Labels not showing on small features

Tags: label, openlayers

I have a project where I use Openlayers in order to display features. On top of each of my features I show a label consisting of the description of that specific feature.

I have noticed that on thin features the vector label does not show. I do not know why this is happening because I have never set a value where the text should of should not be shown.

This is the function that I use in order to set the style and vector label of each feature:

```
style: (feature) => {
      return new Style({
        fill: new Fill({ color: 'rgba(43, 146, 190, 0.4)' }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          width: 3,
          color: 'rgba(43, 146, 190, 1)',
        }),
        text: new Text({
          font: '13px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new Fill({ color: '#fff' }),
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#000',
            width: 2,
          }),
          text: feature.get('description'),
        }),
      });
    },
```

Here you can see that the label is set for most features except those that are small of very thin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already found the solution. In order to show the labels on small or thin features you need to set the `overflow` value of the text object to `true`.

So the function to generate a label based on a feature should be as follows:

```
    style: (feature) => {
      return new Style({
        fill: new Fill({ color: 'rgba(43, 146, 190, 0.4)' }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          width: 3,
          color: 'rgba(43, 146, 190, 1)',
        }),
        text: new Text({
          font: '13px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new Fill({ color: '#fff' }),
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#000',
            width: 2,
          }),
          text: feature.get('description'),
          overflow: true,
        }),
      });
    },
```